# Explaination of SHAP value from XGBoost

Tags: python, xgboost, shap, xgbclassifier

I had fitted a XGBoost model for binary classification. I am trying to understand the fitted model and trying to use [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) to explain the prediction.

However, I get confused by the force plot generated by SHAP. I expected the output value should be smaller than 0 as the predicted probability is less than 0.5. However, the SHAP value shows `8.12`.

Below are my code to generate the result.

```py
import shap
import xgboost as xgb
import json
from scipy.sparse import load_npz

print('Version of SHAP: {}'.format(shap.__version__))
print('Version of XGBoost: {}'.format(xgb.__version__))
```

> Version of SHAP: 0.39.0
>
> Version of XGBoost: 1.4.1

```py
# Read the data
X = load_npz('test_data.npz')
X_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(X)

# Read the selected features
with open('feature_list.json', 'r') as file:
    feature_list = json.load(file)
    
feature_names = [f'Feature {x:04d}' for x in range(len(feature_list))]

# Read the XGBoost model
xgb_model = xgb.Booster()
xgb_model.load_model('xgboost.json')

# Model prediction

model_pred_detail = xgb_model.predict(X_dmatrix, pred_contribs=True)
model_pred_prob = xgb_model.predict(X_dmatrix)
model_pred_detail.shape
```

> (7887, 501)

```py
# Random select a case
xid=4549
print('Predict proba: {:.04f}'.format(model_pred_prob[xid]))
```

> Predict proba: 0.2292

```py
# Doing SHAP way (https://github.com/slundberg/shap)
explainer = shap.Explainer(xgb_model, feature_names=feature_names, algorithm='tree')
shap_values = explainer(X.toarray())

shap.plots.force(shap_values[xid])
```

[image]

However, I get another plot if I use the SHAP value from XGBoost library which looks similar to my expectation.

```py
shap.force_plot(
    model_pred_detail[xid, -1], # From XGBoost.Booster.predict with pred_contribs=True
    model_pred_detail[xid, 0:-1], # From XGBoost.Booster.predict with pred_contribs=True
    feature_names=feature_names, 
    features=X[xid].toarray()
)
```

[image]

Why does this happen? Which one should be the correct SHAP value to explain the XGBoost model?

Thank you for your help.

**Follow up with the reply from** @sergey-bushmanov

Since I cannot share my own data, I reproduce the situation with [open dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datatattle/covid-19-nlp-text-classification/version/1?select=Corona_NLP_train.csv) from Kaggle.

Here is the code for model training:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
import io
from scipy.sparse import save_npz


# parameter setting
class_weight = 10
minNgramLength = 1
maxNgramLength = 3
binary = False
min_df = 20

# Convert to fix the problem of encoding
with open('Corona_NLP_train.csv', 'rb') as file:
    csv_file = file.read()
csv_file2 = csv_file.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')

# Read and split data
df_note = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_file2), encoding='utf-8')
df_note['label'] = np.where(df_note['Sentiment'].str.contains('negative', flags=re.I), 0, 1)

df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df_note, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Tokenization
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.98,
                             min_df=min_df,
                             binary=binary,
                            ngram_range=(minNgramLength, maxNgramLength))
vectorizer.fit(df_train['OriginalTweet'])
X_train = vectorizer.transform(df_train['OriginalTweet']).astype(float)
y_train = df_train['label'].astype(float).reset_index(drop=True)

last_params ={
 'lambda': 0.00016096144192346114,
 'alpha': 0.057770973181367063,
 'eta': 0.19258319097144733,
 'gamma': 0.40032424821976653,
 'max_depth': 9,
 'min_child_weight': 5,
 'subsample': 0.31304772813494836,
 'colsample_bytree': 0.4214452441229869,
 'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 'verbosity': 0,
 'n_estimators': 400
}

classifierCV = xgb.XGBClassifier(**last_params, importance_type='gain')
classifierCV.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=w_train)

# Get the features
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# save model
classifierCV.get_booster().save_model('xgboost.json')

# Save features
import json

with open('feature_list.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps({y:x for x, y in enumerate(feature_names)}))

# save data
save_npz('test_data.npz', X_train)
```

The problem is still here with this model.

Comment: Can you put up a complete start to end reproducible example, including data, and showing up what "problem" you have? What I see so far is a compilation of 2 cases: one without data and with a problem, and another with data, but not specifying what exact problem needs to be solved.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I had put the complete notebook [here](https://www.kaggle.com/felixchan/strange-behavior-shap/notebook) for your reference.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one should be the correct SHAP value to explain the XGBoost model?

Let's make a guess you have a binary classification at hand. Then, what you're getting in your 2nd example is indeed the right decomposition of raw SHAP values:

```
In [1]: from scipy.special import expit
In [2]: expit(-1.21)
Out[2]: 0.22970105095339813
```

Note, `.2297` is close to what you see in your:

> Predict proba: 0.2292

As for:

> Why does this happen?

most probably you have a typo somewhere, but to be sure you have to provide a fully reproducible example, including your data, because codewise both ways calculating SHAP values are correct.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I cannot share my own dataset so I reproduce the situation with open [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datatattle/covid-19-nlp-text-classification/version/1?select=Corona_NLP_train.csv)

Answer (score 0):

I find that the implementation in the XGBoost should be similar to TreeSHAP (Slundberg also joined) instead of `shap.KernelExplainer` because they are using different approaches.

I have tested and see the similar result. You can reproduce here:
[Reproduce results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N11L8.png).

Note that, the attribute `approx_contribs` is recommended to set `False`.